# Rails and slow third-party APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, api

I'm building a Rails app with a huge third-party APIs usage. APIs are not like common web APIs they are about system linux tools, so requests to these APIs will take rather long time (1-5s).

Example:

I have a Document model like

```
def index
  @documents = current_user.documents # just simple DB request
end

def create
  @document = Document.new(document_params)
  @document.sid = call_my_slow_api(@document.title)
  @document.save
end
```

1. Let's say Alice start create request and waiting for reply. Same time Bob start index request. If i have only 1 worker it gonna be a problem (Bob will see the index only after Alice get reply).
2. What is the best way to separate API calls (call_my_slow_api) logic in Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Background jobs might be the way to go, if you are on the latest version of rails 4 (4.3?) activejob is there as a common DSL to tie in with any worker service. If not Resque, DelayedJobs, etc are those you may wanna explore.

Comment: It's not about delayed job, Alice should get the response when the document is ready. So it should be just long loading in browser for here.

Comment: Can you tell me more about why seperating the `call_my_slow_api` from the main thread doesn't help?

Comment: I need to return smth to Alice browser. Let's say i just have to return SID to here. And if i just separate the call, Alice will not receive this information.

Comment: If the information Alice needed to see was the result of `call_my_slow_api` I don't believe there's any way you could show it earlier than the method returns with a result. 

On the other hand you could save `@document` with status as pending and update `@document.sid` once the api returns with appropriate response.

Comment: The idea is not to make it show earlier. The idea is make call_my_slow_api non-blocking (e.g. like node.js does it)

Comment: Which is what background jobs are for, isn't it? It adds whatever you wanted to do into a queue to be processed by a separate worker dedicated to execute those background jobs while your web worker is free to serve Alice.

Comment: No, background jobs are for stuff user doesn't wait right now. While Alice is waiting for response right now.